# How to select variant column with one csv row as multiple columns in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I got a table TABVAR in snowflake which has column Var_Col which is VARIANT type. I load there each row from some csv, so values are like 'val1;val2;val3'.

I know that i can query it as columns directly from csv, but i have to do it other way.

The question is how to query Var_Col to obtain something like:

```
select firstValFromVar_Col, secondValFromVar_Col, thirdValFromVar_Col
from  TABVAR
```

I mean the query like above and result be like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
val1 val2 val3
```

Output of Select * from TABVAR :

```
Var_Col
val1;val2;val3
```

Comment: Variant columns are usually used for semi-structured data (key-value pair), if you loaded from CSV why didn't you used a structured format with a **;** delimiter? You can't request a specific value now from the VARIANT column as you don't have a key for it.

Comment: Can you show us the results of doing a `SELECT * FROM TABVAR` to understand the current schema?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa output added to question.

Comment: @Sergiu thank you for your [actually] answer. There is no answer why csv is in variant, i got to take info from thing which has been done. It appears that what is left is to take values whith substring

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with:

```
select   split_part("Var_Col", ';',  1)
, split_part("Var_Col", ';',  2)
, split_part("Var_Col", ';',  3)
from "TABVAR"
```